# One Electron Universe - Bumping particles back in time?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, spacetime, electrons, time

I understand that John Wheeler's 'One Electron Universe' proposal is not generally accepted, but it's obvious that in disproving such a proposal, or at least discrediting it, we can gain insights to our understanding of Physics. This being said, what I hope to understand is the mechanism that would cause an electron, or any particle, to reverse its direction in time. This is obviously very theoretical, but I imagine that there is decent mathematical models to represent such an interaction just as we can model antimatter particles as time-reversed matter counterparts. This may all fall faulty to the simple fact that I am adopting the assumption that time has a direction, but I feel that that assumption is essential to this theory in the first place. 
My question is simply put - What could cause a particle to reverse its 'direction' in time?

Comment: Be aware that quantum field theories treat particles as excitations in fields rather than things jumping around. Hence having one electron is kind of a non-starter; rather, there is one electron field.

Comment: There is no mechanism for a particle to stop moving foward in time and starting moving back in time. Positrons are not electrons moving backwards in time. Wheeler's suggestion was made before quantum field theory was understood and it is now regarded as a historical artefact of no physical significance. You will not extend your understanding of physics by pursuing it.

Comment: Ah! This makes sense, my understanding of QFT is developed enough to suggest a contradiction but I incorrectly assumed that it had been moved past. Thank you!